# EE Profiler shows by far biggest compute time on "Reprojecting geometry to SR-ORG:6627"?

Tags: google-earth-engine

EE Profiler shows by far the biggest compute time on "Reprojecting geometry to SR-ORG:6627"

Is there a way to import a shapefile into EE already in SR-ORG:6627 projection?

I've tried using QGIS to save a shapefile already in SR-ORG:6627 projection (aka Google Mercator), but without success.  The Profiler still shows the same compute time whether the shapefile (FeatureCollection) is in Geographic Decimal Degrees WGS 84 or in SR-ORG:6627 projection (aka Google Mercator)

Has anyone found a way to import a shapefile as a FeatureCollection already in SR-ORG:6627 so this high Compute time shown in the Profiler can be avoided?

Comment: In follow-up, let me ask it a different way:  What is the exact format of the .prj file expected by EE such that when you import a shapefile as an Asset, and add it to the Map as a featurecollection, NO reprojection occurs (e.g. because the featurecollection is already seen by EE as being in sr-org:6627 / epsg:3857 projection, which is the projection used by the map window)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE'S A DISCUSSION OF THIS TOPIC, along with an explanation of upcoming performance improvements:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-earth-engine-developers/L8Ebq6SV0ug